# How to click an element which may require another icon be clicked on first

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I have list of icons in a column , & at a time only one is clickable ,
but some times icon is not responding/clickable. TO make it clickable we have click refresh button near icon .

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the icon is always visible, I would just add a step to click the refresh icon first every time.

Answer (score 0):

In automated testing services, using an older version of Selenium may cause the problem of not able to click the element on the page. You can try upgrading to a version of Selenium 2.53 or higher and Firefox version 46.0(in case it's not set to this version).

In case the issue still persists, it can be also fixed by adding below line to refresh the page before finding and clicking the desired element:

```
driver.navigate().refresh();
```

Hope that it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have got one more way apart from what @Micheal said that:

1. Click refresh button first before you click the icon
2. It must be obvious that on click of icon, some action will be performed(like opening of pop-up, navigating to other page, etc). So you can check on that action. I mean to say:

   ```
   if(action performed successfully) {
       proceed;
   }
   else {
       click on refresh button;
       click on same icon again;
   }
   ```